# Which disk is \Devide\HarddiskX\drX?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, disk-controller

I'm randomly getting errors in the System Log about a "**Controller error on \Device\Harddisk3\DR3**"; this may be of course a driver error, a NTFS error, or, more seriously, a failing disk.

But I have various physical disks in my computer, and even some RAID volumes managed by the onboard Intel controller (which the OS sees as even other disks).

So: how can I map `\Device\HarddiskX\DRX` to the actual disk it's referring to?

Comment: Enumeration of hard disks should reflect firmware order starting from 0 (DR0)

Comment: But this tends to get quite messed up when more than one controller is involved.